# CORS and same-origin policies request problems in a react bundled app

Tags: javascript, cors, same-origin-policy

Well, im trying to deploy an app bundled with `webpack` and `create-react-app`, the theory here is simple:

Im using environment variables for some things, but in a nutshell in `development` we use an URL like `http://theapp.app.com/api/v3/endpoint`, and it works.

In `production` mode (`yarn build`), the URL is `http://localhost/api/v3/endpoint`, there is the unique change.

Anyway, i'm using the `fetch` API to make my requests, and i'm playing with the `mode` of the fetch config. For `development` it's `mode: 'cors'` because the server it's not in my local machine, and it works perfectly.

In the case of `production` flag, i tried with `mode: 'same-origin'` and `cors` but i get this two errors in the respectively order:

- same-origin enabled in production
  [image]
- cors enabled in production
  [image]

Some aclarations before:

1. Yes, the API app and the bundle are served by the same server/machine.
2. Yep, we have CORS configured on the server (we are using python bottle):

   `@app.hook('after_request')
   def enable_cors():
       response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
       response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
       response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'`
3. Yes, i know that the request origin URL's are not equal in the `same-origin` policy, but with `cors` enabled it explodes too and the `http://data.blabla` is the url from the direct server....  i just don't know what to do.

Any idea? I (sadly) have hours stucked in this.

Comment: `request mode is "same origin" but ... ` - so why is the request mode same origin if the request is actually cross origin? and why is "production mode" using `localhost`? Does the app include a web server?

Comment: Well, i said that i tried with `same-origin` (first image) and then with `cross-origin` (second image).

Comment: sorry, so you did ... *what* is this "localhost" in this scenario? you mention "app" so I'm confused as to what you expect from "localhost"

Comment: @Nano I'm sorry, but the `same-origin` problem couldn't be more obvious: it's _not_ the same origin, as is plainly stated in the error message. If both the app and the API are served from the same server, why are you visting `data.cult...` to see the app when the API url is hardcoded to `localhost...`?

Comment: So, there is a public dns: `xxx.xxxx.com`, the app is right there, then within the same server we want to access the API via localhost (so it wouldn't needed to be out in the open) and that's the problem. When accesed via the url in both cases ( cors and same origin) it works, but when trying to access it via localhost it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `localhost` on the server side is no problem, since it will point to that same server. But if you try to do that on the client side, `http://localhost` is pointing *to that very same client*. If Javascript running in a browser is requesting something from `http://localhost`, you're trying to talk to the browser's computer, not the web app's host.
It didn't even occur to me that you aren't realizing that.

When you said the API is on `localhost`, I assumed that this app is going to be used only on clients that already have the API server running on them.

If people on the outside are supposed to use this app, the API has to be exposed as well. If you want to hide your insecure API, you'd have to implement an exposed but secure in-between API. Or, you know, secure the actual API :)